# cursor ripple effect for screencasts and other useful action visibility tools

Tags: windows, mac, unix, screencasts

I was wondering whether someone could point me to any tools available for unix/windows/mac that enable useful screen cast options such as showing a circle that ripples out everytime a mouse click occurs. I can't seem to find the right phraseology to search for this so was hoping someone had a better idea than me.

Any additional useful tools for this type of thing would be welcome as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recommended on both Lifehacker ([HERE](http://lifehacker.com/5410229/five-best-screencasting-tools)) and on MakeUseOf ([HERE](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/show-dont-tell-3-best-free-screencasting-tools-for-windows/)), [CamStudio](http://camstudio.org/) is able to do want you want. CamStudio is a free and open source program that comes with good amount of features, including `Visual Click Feedback` (the feature you were seeking).

The forum post [HERE](http://camstudio.org/forum/discussion/382/highlighting-mouse-clicks/p1) details what you need to do to enable `Visual Click Feedback`. After you have downloaded and installed CamStudio, it instructs you to go to `Options>Cursor Options` and enable `Highlight Cursor` and `Enable Visual Click Feedback`. The next time you record your screen, you will notice the desired "ripple effect."

*Please note: the ripple effect will not show WHILE you are recording, it is only visible in the recorded video.*

Comment: Great, I've downloaded it and had a look around, This seems to give me just what i wanted :)

Answer (score 1):

This question was created in 2014, and it's 2021 now. For people who came here via google search, here are the solutions that I have collected to highlight your mouse with ripple effect in Windows system:

1. Use CamStudio to record your video: https://camstudio.org/
   Pros/Cons: it's not free.
2. Use ActivePresenter to record your video: https://atomisystems.com/download/
   Pros/Cons: it free for personal usage, but not free for commercial usage.
3. Buy a program called PoitnerFocus: http://www.pointerfocus.com/
   Pros/Cons: it's kind of free if you don't want to pay for it, but it will keep popping up a message every few minutes asking you to pay.
4. Use an open source AutoHotkey script: https://github.com/yunyi-the-coder/mouse-cursor-highlight-windows  (This is the one I am currently using for my screen recording with OBS)
   Pros/Cons: it's a free open source software for both personal and commercial usage, but it doesn't have a GUI interface for you to configure it -- you will need to configure it through a "settings" file instead of a GUI.